# How do I pass a dynamic variable to javascripts .forEach() function?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, foreach

How do I pass a dynamic variable `image[i]` into the .forEach() function?
I get this error when I try to use my variable: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target`

```
images.forEach((image[i]) => {
  if(iter == 0){ ctx.drawImage(image[i], 60, 270);}
  if(iter == 1){ ctx.drawImage(image[i], 80, 270);}
  if(iter == 2){ ctx.drawImage(image[i], 100, 270);}
  console.log(iter);
});
```

Edit:

Here is the whole function

```
    // Account UI
    function accountUI(str) {
        // Parse MOTD for use
        var motd = str.match( /<motd>[^<>]*?<\/motd>/igm );

        // Clean un-needed spaces & tags
        var motd_clean = motd[0];
        motd_clean = motd_clean.replace("<motd>", "");
        motd_clean = motd_clean.replace("</motd>", "");
        motd_clean = motd_clean.replace(/[\r]+/g, '');
        motd_clean = $.trim(motd_clean);

        // Create textarea for MOTD
        $("#can_wrapper").append('<textarea id="motd" name="motd" disabled>' + motd_clean + '</textarea>');

        // Create blue background for players
        ctx.fillStyle = "#333399";
        ctx.fillRect(2, 255, 596, 181);

        // Parse player names for use
        var players = str.match( /<players>([\s\S]*?)<\/players>/m );
        var players = players[0];
        var item = str.match( /<item([\s\S]*?)>/mg );

        // For every player run iteration
        var image = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
            // Position for players on account screen
            if(i == 0){ var pos = "61px";var iter = 0;}
            if(i == 1){ var pos = "168px";var iter = 1;}
            if(i == 2){ var pos = "275px";var iter = 2;}
            console.log(i);
            console.log("1 -> " + iter);
            // Gets player name from string
            var player = item[i].match( /([A-Z])\w+/g );

            // Create player div for mouse interaction
            var player_el = $('<div class="cursor player" id="player'+ player +'"></div>');
            $("#can_wrapper").append(player_el);
            $("#player"+ player).css({"position": "absolute", "height": "50px", "width": "50px", "left": ""+ pos +"", "top": "271px", "cursor": "grab", "cursor": "-webkit-grab"});

            // Get player name for hover action
            var player_name_el = player;
            document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#player'+ player +':hover::after','content: "'+player_name_el+'";');

            /**
             * Promisify loading an image
             * @param {String} imagePath The web location of the image
             * @returns {Promise} A Promise that will resolve to an Image
             */
            function loadImage(imagePath) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    image[i] = new Image();
                    image[i].addEventListener("load", () => {
                        resolve(image[i]);
                    });
                    image[i].addEventListener("error", (err) => {
                        reject(err);
                    });
                    image[i].src = 'https://www.example.com/interface/images/body/' + imagePath;
                });
            }

            var imageSources = ['v1456.png', 'vbody0.png','vhead14.png','v1960.png','v578.png','v1221.png', 'v3063.png']; // url and order

            Promise
                .all(imageSources.map(ii => loadImage(ii)))
                .then((images) => {
                    images.forEach((image[i]) => {
                        if(iter == 0){ ctx.drawImage(image[i], 60, 270);}
                        if(iter == 1){ ctx.drawImage(image[i], 80, 270);}
                        if(iter == 2){ ctx.drawImage(image[i], 100, 270);}
                        console.log(iter);
                    });
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you don't need the `[i]` as the first parameter is the current value

Answer (score 4):

The variable before the `=>` is the name you give each item of the array you're `forEach`ing on in the loop. You don't need to use the `[]` notation, just a name:

```
images.forEach((image) => {
  if(iter == 0){ ctx.drawImage(image, 60, 270);}
  if(iter == 1){ ctx.drawImage(image, 80, 270);}
  if(iter == 2){ ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 270);}
  console.log(iter);
});
```

Comment: Also it looks like iter is the iteration, which atm seems like is outside the loop. However    forEach    allows you to pass a second parameter which is the index, as shown in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the parameters into an array and call the values with an index.

```
images.forEach(image => ctx.drawImage((image[i], [60, 80, 100][iter], 270)):
```

Comment: I get this error: `index.html:414 TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type` im guessing because its still expecting `image[i]`

Comment: where is `i` coming from?

Comment: Line 27 in the updated part of my question. `for (var i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a global image array, try following code

You also can use [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

```js
// Account UI
function accountUI(str) {
 // Parse MOTD for use
 var motd = str.match(/<motd>[^<>]*?<\/motd>/igm);

 // Clean un-needed spaces & tags
 var motd_clean = motd[0];
 motd_clean = motd_clean.replace("<motd>", "");
 motd_clean = motd_clean.replace("</motd>", "");
 motd_clean = motd_clean.replace(/[\r]+/g, '');
 motd_clean = $.trim(motd_clean);

 // Create textarea for MOTD
 $("#can_wrapper").append('<textarea id="motd" name="motd" disabled>' + motd_clean + '</textarea>');

 // Create blue background for players
 ctx.fillStyle = "#333399";
 ctx.fillRect(2, 255, 596, 181);

 // Parse player names for use
 var players = str.match(/<players>([\s\S]*?)<\/players>/m);
 var players = players[0];
 var item = str.match(/<item([\s\S]*?)>/mg);

 // For every player run iteration
 
 for (var i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
  // Position for players on account screen
  if (i == 0) { var pos = "61px"; var iter = 0; }
  if (i == 1) { var pos = "168px"; var iter = 1; }
  if (i == 2) { var pos = "275px"; var iter = 2; }
  console.log(i);
  console.log("1 -> " + iter);
  // Gets player name from string
  var player = item[i].match(/([A-Z])\w+/g);

  // Create player div for mouse interaction
  var player_el = $('<div class="cursor player" id="player' + player + '"></div>');
  $("#can_wrapper").append(player_el);
  $("#player" + player).css({ "position": "absolute", "height": "50px", "width": "50px", "left": "" + pos + "", "top": "271px", "cursor": "grab", "cursor": "-webkit-grab" });

  // Get player name for hover action
  var player_name_el = player;
  document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#player' + player + ':hover::after', 'content: "' + player_name_el + '";');

  /**
   * Promisify loading an image
   * @param {String} imagePath The web location of the image
   * @returns {Promise} A Promise that will resolve to an Image
   */
  function loadImage(imagePath) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let image = new Image();
    imag.addEventListener("load", () => {
     resolve(image);
    });
    image.addEventListener("error", (err) => {
     reject(err);
    });
    image.src = 'https://www.example.com/interface/images/body/' + imagePath;
   });
  }

  var imageSources = ['v1456.png', 'vbody0.png', 'vhead14.png', 'v1960.png', 'v578.png', 'v1221.png', 'v3063.png']; // url and order

  Promise.all(imageSources.map(ii => loadImage(ii))).then((images) => {
   images.forEach((image) => {
    if (iter == 0) { ctx.drawImage(image, 60, 270); }
    if (iter == 1) { ctx.drawImage(image, 80, 270); }
    if (iter == 2) { ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 270); }
    console.log(iter);
   });
  }).catch((err) => {
   console.error(err);
  });

 }
}
```

Comment: This gives me: `index.html:419 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` for the `images[i]` in the 3 `ctx.drawImage(images[i], 60, 270`

Comment: just looked at your updated question you need only image, which is already answered.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm guessing it draws the image as it should, it shows that it drew 21 images in the 3rd iteration. Meaning my `if (iter == 1)` are not working, and everything is drawing on the last one.

Comment: change all var to let specially in first for loop